# Inno-Setup: Desinstalar sem permissão de administrador

Tags: windows, pascal, inno-setup

Usando *Inno Setup*, preciso que quando um programa for instalado na máquina, por um usuário **administrador**, possa ser desinstalado por um usuário padrão. O parâmetro **PrivilegesRequired** está como **lowest**, mas o problema permanece.

Fiz testes em algumas máquinas aqui *(Todas Windows 7)*, e em algumas máquinas eu consegui desinstalar o programa utilizando o usuário padrão, porém houveram outras máquinas que não permitiram e solicitaram usuário administrador.

Não consegui identificar um padrão do porquê não funcionou em algumas máquinas e também não achei nada com pesquisas na internet.

O diretório no qual o programa é instalado é o C:\;

Não estou usando a seção [Registry] e todos os parâmetros na seção [Dirs] usa Permissions: users-modify.

Comment: E aí? Encontrou alguma solução ou motivo? Os ambientes e permissões de usuários eram exatamente iguais?